# How to stamp only the last page of a PDF

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have the following code to stamp a pdf with a an image that is converted to a pdf. Everything seems to work except for it stamps every page in the pdf. How can i get it to only stamp the last page of the pdf?

```
pdftk temp-pdfjam.pdf stamp signature-pdfjam.pdf output final/finalized.pdf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work only with pdftk, it looks like you will have to extract the last page using the `cat` command of pdftk, stamp it, then join it with the first pages - or prepare a PDF with the appropriate number of blank pages and use the "multistamp" command.

Comment: Is there another way that you know of to be able to do this that's easier?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. You could certainly implement something yourself, but I doubt that would be easier. Maybe there are other tools that can do it, but I don't know any.

Answer (score 4):

A working snippet using `pdftk`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

input=$1
watermark=$2
output=$3
abl=/tmp/all_but_last.pdf
last=/tmp/last.pdf
last_stamped=/tmp/last_stamped.pdf

# detach
pdftk $1 cat 1-r2 output $abl 
pdftk $1 cat end output $last 
#Stamp
pdftk $last stamp $watermark output $last_stamped
#Attach
pdftk $abl $last_stamped cat output $output
```

Run it as a shell script :

`./stamp_last_page.sh input.pdf stamp.pdf output.pdf`

Comment: Alas, the size of the file suffers from the treatment by `pdftk`

Answer (score 1):

Try [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/):

```
cpdf -stamp-on stamp.pdf in.pdf 1 -o out.pdf
```

You can replace '1' with any page range you want.

Comment: note that cpdf has "a special not-for-commercial-use license" (https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries/blob/master/LICENSE) -- for applications like this that are handled well by open source tools I don't see a point in investing in cpdf - not sure if it has an edge in some special use case though

Comment: in a quick test, cdpf did not bloat file size like pdftk did